# Omniauth + OpenID in Ruby: Google OpenID authentication in a popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid, omniauth, google-authentication

Using the omniauth and omniauth-openid gems in Ruby and am looking for a way to have a pop up window during authentication.

According to Google's OpenID docs (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) the OpenID User Interface 1.0 has a setting to allow for popup authentication.

I've checked ruby-openid (which is a dependency of omniauth-openid) to confirm that it has been upgraded to support the OpenID User Interface 1.0.

Now I'm just trying to figure out the last piece of the puzzle... I assume it would be somewhere in my config settings, which currently look like this:

```
require 'omniauth-openid'
require 'openid/store/filesystem'

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :open_id, :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
end
```

--- UPDATE: (5/8/2013) ---

So I've hacked the rack-openid gem to include the openid ui extension and now my URL looks as follows:

> https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.ax.if_available=ext4%2Cext5%2Cext6%2Cext7%2Cext8&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.required=ext0%2Cext1%2Cext2%2Cext3&openid.ax.type.ext0=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ax.type.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson&openid.ax.type.ext2=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Ffirst&openid.ax.type.ext3=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Flast&openid.ax.type.ext4=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Ffriendly&openid.ax.type.ext5=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Fcity%2Fhome&openid.ax.type.ext6=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Fstate%2Fhome&openid.ax.type.ext7=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Fweb%2Fdefault&openid.ax.type.ext8=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fmedia%2Fimage%2Faspect11&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.ax=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.ns.ui=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fui%2F1.0&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1999&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1999%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback%3F_method%3Dpost&openid.sreg.optional=postcode%2Cnickname&openid.sreg.required=email%2Cfullname&openid.ui.mode=popup

All the parameters look correct, specifically the openid.ns.ui parameter and the openid.ui.mode parameter; however, the behavior has not changed... Am I doing something wrong? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take a look through the source-code of the actual omniauth-openid gem and it seems to be, that this functionality is not added. Try to make a feature-request.